# How to implement Context service in web application?

Tags: sdl-tridion, context-engine, sdl-mobile

1. As per documentation I have installed Ambient Data Framework
2. Installed Context Engine cartridge as a service.
3. Configured the Discovery service in CD storage config of the application.
4. Added the below configuration in order to enable First request device capability detection
5. Added the Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.dll version (current version:8.1.0.1229) in project reference
6. Build is successful.
7. By going through @Nuno TridionContextEngineWrapper code I am able to understand how to use the API.

While I am using AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore.GetAll() to read Claims  I am getting the below error. Am I missing anything?

Unable to cast object of type 'Sdl.Web.Delivery.Core.Collections.ImmutableDictionary`2[System.Uri,System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Uri,System.Object]'.

9. When I inspect the claim store I am getting the below values
   [1]: {taf:request:uri}
   [2]: {taf:response:cookie:generation}
   [3]: {taf:request:full_url}
   [4]: {taf:server:variables}
   [5]: {taf:tracking:id}
   [6]: {taf:request:cookies}
   [7]: {taf:request:headers}
   [8]: {taf:session:attributes}
   [9]: {taf:session:id}

I am not seeing Claims related to Context which is required to get device information.

Why I am not seeing the Context related claims?

Update: I found that the above error is due to Mixed Approach, Sdl.Web.Delivery.Core dll is rest API and trying to access the content using In Process API.

Update: Java Version mismatch causing my application to hang and other errors.
Once Installed Java 8 I am able to run my application
Then Found that the documentation provided by SDL contains approach for restful API only.

Now my doubt is SDL Mobile claims I am able to read if I deploy my application in a server.
Where it is failing in my local machine which is running windows 7.

In 2013 SP1 we were able to read SDL Mobile claims in local.

Do you know any prerequisites we need to install in windows 7 to read SDL Mobile claims?

Comment: Which version are you using? What does "Installed Context Engine Cartridge as a service" mean, exactlty?

Comment: Please share the actual code so that we can give you pointers. thanks

Comment: Did you install the Context microservice + configured the cartridge: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-43EA9C80-05C9-4078-B2DD-ECA036FC725C

Comment: Yes I installed , Context microservice + configured the cartridge used the below code from Github and I am using dll version 8.1.0.1229 https://github.com/NunoLinhares/TridionContextEngineWrapper/blob/master/Sdl.Tridion.Context/ContextEngine.cs and I received the above error.{ Dictionary<Uri, object> claims = (Dictionary<Uri, object>)AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore.GetAll(); }

Comment: That code was written for mobile in Tridion 2011... very unlikely to work today "as is"